# Regular expression in JavaScript - Replace Image src attribute

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript I have a string containing a DOM fragment. How would I find and replace the src attribute of an image?

I would like to replace the path of all images with a new path but keeping the image name. Not all the paths are the same and can come from various locations.
My regular expression skills are poor at best.

For example:

```
Change

   <img src='path/to/image/name.jpg' />

into 

   <img src='newPath/name.jpg' />
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
str.replace(/src='(?:[^'\/]*\/)*([^']+)'/g, "src='newPath/$1'");
```

Comment: doesnt seem to work. changes 'http://blog.internetnews.com/skerner/smk/testpilot.png' into
'http://newPath/blog.internetnews.com/skerner/smk/testpilot.png'

Comment: It will do.  You need to use "src='newPath/$2'" as the replacement

Comment: Editted the answer to fix this

Comment: Ah, this works for one image but will not match all images. Is this possible

Comment: @redsquare: Just forgot a quantifier and the global flag. And the `$1` *is* correct.

Answer (score 13):

Took gumbo's answer and added a few more things to improve it:

- If the input string contains something
  other than `<img>` tags that may have
  a `src` attribute - this will no longer
  matches/replace them.
- The `src` attribute may be
  using single or double quotes.
- The test being case insensitive.

Resulting in:

```
string.replace(/<img([^>]*)\ssrc=(['"])(?:[^\2\/]*\/)*([^\2]+)\2/gi, "<img$1 src=$2newPath/$3$2");
```

Answer (score 4):

If using raw (non-DOM) data such as HTML in string form, above doesn't match double quote chars. This code may prove useful, too:

```
root     = serviceURL("file") + "&src=" + encodeURIComponent(root);
// html itself
html     = html.replace(/src=['"](?:[^"'\/]*\/)*([^'"]+)['"]/g, "src='" + root + "/$1'");
```

Comment: Much better solution

Answer (score 1):

```
replace(/(.*)\/(.*)/, "newPath/$2");
```

Comment: that's odd.  It worked when I tried it in this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html

Answer (score 1):

The above solutions doesn't work well in my case, where i had to replace all relative path to absolute path before storing it in DB. But here's my solution in case mine work for anyone else. Cheers.

```
replace(/<img([^>]*)\ssrc=(['"])(\/[^\2*([^\2\s<]+)\2/gi, "<img$1 src=$2" + BaseURL + "$3$2");
```

Answer (score 0):

I used these expression in my project, worked like charm, handling all cases like, quote, double quote, multiple image tags in text etc.
In Javascript

```
text.replace(/\<img([^>]*)\ssrc=('|")([^>]*)\2\s([^>]*)\/\>/gi, "<img$1 src=$2newPath/$3$2 $4/>");
```

In PHP

```
preg_replace('/\<img([^>]*)\ssrc=(\'|\")([^>]*)\2\s([^>]*)\/\>/', "<img$1 src=$2newPath/$3$2 $4/>",$text);
```