# Error with find() after correct result

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome-extension

I have some errors in my extension. I have this code that do a find() on an external page:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.subspedia.tv/traduzioni.php',
    success: function(data) {
        $(data).find('.itemListaSerie').each(function() {
            console.log($(this).attr('title'));
        });
    }
});
```

The find function work correctly but after the result I have a lot of errors that say "File not found" on all images in the page that I'm doing the request.
The screen show my result:
[image]

Comment: I'm assuming you're appending the HTML returned in the request to the page, if so the paths to the images are incorrect based on the current path of the page. You need to amend the paths to find the correct files. There's no specific issue to fix given the code you've provided.

Comment: Is `data` a valid jquery obejct?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, I append "$(this).attr('title') to the page. I don't need the image but only the title that I correctly get it, I need to exclude the images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to post process the relate links like `immagini/serie/covers/33.png` for each of the images, and convert them into something like

```
http://www.subspedia.tv/immagini/serie/covers/33.png
```

instead of using it as is

EDIT:
The images loaded are probably due to the `$(data)`. If you need only the titles, then you should replace the src of all the tags before `$(data)`

```
success: function(data) {
    var strippedData = data.replace(/src='(?:[^'\/]*\/)*([^']+)'/g, "");
    $(strippedData).find('.itemListaSerie').each(function() {
        console.log($(this).attr('title'));
    });
```

Credit to @Gumbo for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1298545/2599266) on regex for matching src. Note, this will remove all src attributes in the page

Comment: I don't need the images, I need somehow to get only the title, and to exclude the images.

Comment: You're getting them. Look above the errors. 4 titles for each of the `.itemListaSerie` in the page

Comment: @master94ga added an edit. Please try it out and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

After your success function, using **$(data)** you create an element that contain all the html from http://www.subspedia.tv/traduzioni.php so, the document is looking for all the script, css and the images included in that page.
try to replace all the **img** as words in **data** as string and then call **$(data).find...**.

Hope this helps you! Anche se mi sarei spiegato meglio in Italiano ;)